# Variation of steepest descent/Laplace methods for non-exponential integrands

Tags: cv.complex-variables, na.numerical-analysis, integration, approximation-theory, applied-mathematics

I was wondering if versions of the Laplace/steepest descent methods exists for integrals of the type

$$\int_C f(z) M(\lambda g(z)) dz$$

for $\lambda >>0$ functions $f(z), g(z): \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and where $M(z)$ is a "stretched exponential" of some sort (e.g. Mittag Leffler function, Hypergeometric functions).

As far as I can see, for the case when $f,g,M$ are real functions it is easy to mimick the formal derivation of the Laplace method, if, say, we can explicitly compute the integral of $M(-x^2)$ which should look like a delta around the origin. Can all this be made precise?

Comment: Well, you can always write $M(z)=e^{\log M(z)}$...

Comment: Sure, but then $\lambda$ would be in the wrong place. It does not reduce to the the Laplace problem.

Answer (score 1):

The OP asks for steepest descent for a "stretched exponential" : if $M(z)=e^{z^\beta}$, with $\beta>0$, then $M(\lambda g(z))=e^{\lambda^\beta g^\beta}$ and there is no problem with steepest descent in the $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ limit. This would apply, for example, to the Mittag-Leffler function $E_{2,1}$ (with $\beta=1/2$). If $M(z)$ is a rational function, for example $E_{0,1}$, the large-$\lambda$ asymptotics is not governed by steepest descent.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the first example of course. Howrver in the general case of special functions is the message that only the leading order of $M$ "infinity" matters? If so,  as far as I know the $E_\alpha$ functions has Stokes lines and the $\exp(z^\alpha)$ asymptotic is only valid in certain regions. Similarly, the $_1F_1$ is exponential for $Re(z)>0$ and eational for $Re(z)<0$. Do we have then applicability of the steepest descent only for appropriate contours?

Comment: perhaps it would be helpful if you give an explicit example of an integral you would like to see evaluated for large $\lambda$.

Comment: I guess my question was not very clear. What I meant is the following: in the above integral can we conclude that for large $\lambda$ has order $M(\lambda g(z_0))/\sqrt{\lambda}$, when $M$ has properties similar to the exponential (when the "naive" Laplace Taylor development on the real line is applied) and $z_0$ is a saddle point for $g$?

Comment: Yes you are right:maybe  this is better tackled speicfically. As in my first comment, let us say as in my comment above $M(z)=E_\alpha(z)$, or $M(z)=_1F_1(a,b;z)$, $f(z)=1$, $g(z)$ has a single saddle point $z_0$ on $Im(z)=c >0$ where $Re(z)$ attains its maximum.